# setting data context of silverlight user control leaves the control as always visible

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls, visibility

I have a 'searchwin.xaml' user control in a Silverlight page called Mainpage.xaml. 'searchwin' has its own viewmodel 'searhwinVM'. I have set searchwin's datacontext to its viewmodel in the Mainpage xaml like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<vm:SearchWin  x:Name="SearchWinVM" x:Key="SearchWinVM" /> </UserControl.Resources>

<part:SearchWin ..... {other properties here}
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsSearchVisible}"
DataContext="{StaticResource SearchWinVM}"/>
```

This search control I want to set as invisible by default and visible only when I change to a particular value in my listbox which is on the mainpage.xaml. Setting the datacontext of the UC in the mainpage.xaml or programatically in the mainpage.xaml.cs causes the control to always be visble. I cant get it to hide now. If I remove the datacontext it works well as expected. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that your converter is being called at all? I'd just put a breakpoint in and see what happens.

Comment: yes it is being called. In the same code when I take out the line DataContext="{StaticResource SearchWinVM}" .. it works as expected. some how setting the datacontext in the xaml or in the mainpage.xaml.cs is leaving the control as forever visible!!

Comment: So, if it is being called, does the parameter (that is supposed to be mapped to IsSearchVisible) have the desired value (obviously, you expect this to be false) and if yes, does your converter return the corresponding Visibility value (which should be Collapsed)?

Comment: when setting the datacontext in xaml it doesnt seem to be calling the BooleanToVisibilityConverter. Strange! ...when I take off the DataContext property it works.. What has the DataContext got to do with my converter being called or not..?

Comment: Well, you are binding to IsSearchVisible. If the DataContext is set, this property will refer to DataContext object, so it has everything to do with it. I don't understand the part where you say that 'it works' if you remove DataContext - what would the converter be bound to if there's no DataContext?

Comment: IsSearchVisible is a property of the mainpageViewModel. on a listbox change I load a usercontrol[SearchWin] that has a button and search popup. The popup is made visible on the button click in the UC. I hide the entire UC by default. The minute a particular value is selected on the listbox on the Mainpage.xaml its viewmodel [mainpageViewModel] should make the searchwin UC visible.

Comment: This line is in the mainpage.xaml <part:SearchWin ..... {other properties here} 
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsSearchVisible}" 
DataContext="{StaticResource SearchWinVM}"/>. 
The datacontext for Mainpage.xaml is set in mainpage.xaml.cs. So when I take out the datacontext above [DataContext="{StaticResource SearchWinVM}"] the mainpageViewModel sets the IsSearchVisible and the converter does its job. But when I add that line in the control's declaration, it fails.

Comment: I hope that by 'I hide the entire UC by default' you don't mean you're setting the Visiblity property by hand in code? Since that would (I think) remove the binding permanently.

Comment: I think I understand. When there's no DataContext set on the search control, the parent's (or parent's parent etc) one is used. Since your main VM contains the matching property, all is fine. Once you set the search VM, since it doesn't contain the IsSearchVisible property, the code will of course not work. What do you expect to happen? This is completely normal.